# If statement not working in C

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm creating a program that'll measure the elapsed times between dates. I've written several if statements to throw back an error message and end the program.

e.g.

```
    if (monthOne == 2 && dayOne > 28) {
    printf("Invalid date.\n")
    return 0; }
```

I also have if statements for months that have similar values set up like this with similar conditions to execute.

```
    if ( monthOne == 4 || 6 || 9 || 11 && dayOne > 30)
```

Yet I always get my invalid date message returned and the program ends. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Second `if` is kind of messy isn't it?

Comment: The `||` operator doesn't work like that!

Comment: What types are `monthOne` and `dayOne`?

Comment: What happens during a leap year? (February 29 is valid)

Answer (score 3):

You should change your second `if` to this:

```
if ((monthOne == 4 || monthOne == 6 || monthOne == 9 || monthOne == 11) && dayOne > 30)
```

Evaluating `monthOne == 4 || 6` is always true because 6 is different from 0 and the remaining expressions are "short circuited" (not evaluated). You also need to use an extra set of parenthesis because `&&` has higher precedence compared to `||`.

Answer (score 2):

Place a semicolon after `printf` in first `if`.

```
printf("Invalid date.\n");
```

Change your second `if` to

```
if((monthOne == 4 || monthOne == 6 || monthOne == 9 || monthOne == 11) && dayOne > 30)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make changes to your `if` statement

```
if((monthOne == 4 || monthOne == 6 || monthOne == 9 || monthOne == 11) && dayOne > 30)
```

to know more about how `OR` operator works check wikipedia **http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B**
and msdn 
**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z68fx2f1.aspx**